# Getting multiple values from an activity and setting them in edittext

Tags: android

I am getting multiple  selected items from a list Activity.Now how can i set that String Array  to edit text.I want to show multiple values in edittext

Comment: post you code here. where are you try..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for(int i=0;i<strarray.length;i++)
{
youredittext.append(strarray[i]+"\n");
}
```

Comment: @SammarJaved you can accept this as answer by clicking on right mark beside answer..And now you can vote I think